# Why can’t I select a <td> using its class and data-test attributes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="ok" data-test="12-12 00">xxx</td>
        <td class="ok" data-test="13-12 00">xxx</td>
        <td class="ok" data-test="14-12 00">xxx</td>
        <td class="ok" data-test="15-12 00">xxx</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

​I would like get the `<td>` where `data-test` = `"14-12 00"`. Here’s my code:

```
alert($('td .ok[data-test="14-12 00"]').text());​
```

Why is this not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/LqD5h/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
alert($('td.ok[data-test="14-12 00"]').text());​
```

(Notice there is no space between `td` and `.ok`).

You were originally trying to select all elements with classname `ok` that are descendants of a `td` and bear a certain `data-test` value.

Comment: @paul Thanks for the edit, should have made that more obvious.

Comment: @Asad: you’re very welcome, that’s why everything on Stack Overflow is editable — it’s always easier to spot stuff like that in other people’s answers.

Answer (score 2):

How about another way to skin this cat?

```
alert($('tr .ok[data-test="14-12 00"]').text());​
```

Notice, `td` changed to `tr`. :-)